# How to determine if a user has an Outlook 'out of office' notice active?

Tags: outlook

I would love to know when someone has set an out of office notice in their Outlook so I can make adjustments within my app using that knowledge.

Does anyone know if the assistant or if Outlook itself reports this information anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOF settings are not directly exposed through the Outlook Object Model.
You can however read the OOF state using the `PR_OOF_STATE` property (DASL name is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B"`) using `Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.
The OOF text is stored in a hidden message with the message class of `"IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft"` in the Inbox folder. It can be accessed using `Folder.GetStorage`.

Other OOF related properties can be accessed using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), EWS, or Redemption (I am its author - see [RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant.htm) object)